# Number sequence - 5 3 8 9 1 27

Tags: number-sequence

Fill in the correct number in this sequence:

5 3 8 9 1 27 ?

The options are:
18, 54, 38, 14 or 13.

I can see the pattern of 3, 9, 27 but other than that I am clueless.

Source: a publicly available practice test in a book for an IQ-test I got via a friend in the Netherlands.

Comment: I added more explanation on the source.

Comment: Upon first observation, it seems like there are two sequences; there is the 3, 9, 27 pattern alternating with a pattern that adds three to each term, ignoring the tens. Unfortunately, the answer must apparently include tens so that is a circumstantial relationship.

Comment: I also noticed that the sequence includes each digit between 1 and 9 exactly once, except 4 and 6, in case that means anything.

Comment: It seems I found similar question without 27.. According to the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences: http://oeis.org/search?go=Search&language=english&q=5,3,8,9,1.. next number is sequence might be 1 or 3..

Comment: @kanoo: I think you are right. I double checked and it really says 1 but they probably made a mistake: it should have been 11. In that case 14 must be the correct answer. They probably forget the additional 1.

Comment: @Dennispuz IQ questions like this don't use obscure tricks or require special knowledge. The sequence `3 9 27` is immediately obvious, but `5 8 1` has no natural continuation with any of the five options offered. Every option in IQ questions usually has *some* kind of plausibility to it. Thus,  in this case, we have `18` and `54`, which are multiples of `3` and `9`. But what about `13` and `38`? Well, with `11` in the original sequence, we'd have a run of `9 11 ... 13` near the end, and there's also `11 + 27 = 38` - both of which look like plausible "false leads".

Comment: @ekhumoro I disagree.  If 11 would be present then indeed 11 + 27  = 38 but that pattern is not continuosly found in the sequence. I agree on the absence of obscure tricks or special knowledge for this reason the subsequence 5 8 11 14 makes sense. It is just an addition of 3.

Comment: @Dennispuz You completely missed my point. If `1` really was part of the sequence, those other options would make ***no sense at all***. But with `11`, they at least make ***some*** sense (as wrong answers). It's only because you now know that `14` is the correct answer that you can say that the other options are wrong, and why. Before that, you were "clueless" (according to your question). Those other options will only mislead someone *who doesn't already know the answer*.

Comment: I understand now. I agree.

Answer (score 2):

i think the answer is 14 because, in odd position 5*8*1=40, in even position 3*9*27=729.
then you add 40 to 729= 769. then 769 -53 ( obtained by adding the numbers of the sequence) = 716. 7+1+6 you obtain 14.
or you can 3*9*27= 729 then 7+2+9=18,
5*8*1=40 you obtain 4.
18-4=14

Comment: Can you explain why you would do all of these things? Can we produce previous numbers in the sequence in a similar way?

Answer (score 1):

One way of thinking about it would be

> to observe that none of the sequence have distinct prime factors. Of the choices given the only one preserving this property is $13$.

This would mean that the problem is only solvable because of the specific set of choices provided.

Answer (score 1):

By visual inspection we see $3^1,3^2,3^3$ form an ascending sequence of powers of 3. The five given numbers cannot be the next term of this sequence. The numbers $5,1$ are divisible by themselves but $8$ is a composite number. I say the answer is $14$ because $5+1+8=14$.

If the missing number is $14$, then the numbers $18,54,38,14$ have a common factor, the number $2$. In addition to that, by subtraction of these numbers we obtain the squares $54-38=2^4$ and $18-14=2^2$.