# An ad-hoc number sequence to solve

Tags: number-sequence

Inspired by [another question here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75313/number-sequence-5), I thought I might create my own:

Fill in the correct number in this sequence:

5, 3, 4, 9, 8, 3, 5, ...

And of course, explain why :)

Comment: rot13(gur ryyvcfvf vf qrpvrivat, nf guvf frdhrapr vf svavgr)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> 12.

My reasoning is

> Taking each word of the sentence "Fill in the correct number in this sequence:", count the number of letters and add the number of vowels. Equivalently, each consonant adds 1, and each vowel adds 2 to the sum of the word.
>  The numbers given correspond to "Fill... this" so the next word is "sequence". With eight letters, four of which are vowels, the total would be 12.

Comment: Nice .. I'll have to think of something a little trickier :)