# An ad-hoc number sequence to solve 2

Tags: number-sequence

Continuing on from my [last effort](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75315/an-ad-hoc-number-sequence-to-solve), let's try something new.

"7, 14, 29, 62, 132," have I, but now what should I do?

Which number comes next?

[image]

Hint - mouseover if you want to see the next number in the sequence:

> 282 comes next - but then what comes after 282?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> 278

because

> the pattern is
>  $7$
>  $7 \times 2+0=14$
>  $14\times 2+1=29$
>   $29\times 2+4=62$
>  $62\times 2+8=132$
>  Following the pattern from [here](http://oeis.org/A006578), I think the next number will be $132\times 2+14=278$

Comment: That's kind of cool - and a cool resource link - but it's not the pattern I followed. Apologies that the two overlap, but they do veer at the next term. I note in the meta here that each question should have a unique solution. I'm thinking that will be very hard to guarantee! So - yes - I agree your solution works, but I still had another in mind... Well done on finding that pattern!

Comment: That's a challenge in making of number sequence ;) maybe to clarify, you can add one or two numbers

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to add another number - but my hope is to limit the first set to 5 numbers, wait and see whether anyone can pick the correct pattern, and if not, then add the sixth. Maybe give it a day?

Comment: the next number has been added as a hint. Naturally, we now need to figure out what follows that.

Answer (score -1):

> $7$
>  $7×2+0=14$
> $14×2+1=29$
> $29×2+4=62$
> $62×2+8=132$
> $132×2+16=280$ 
>  Therefore the answer is 280.

Comment: please cover your anser with >! [answer] so noone gets spoiled :)

Comment: Hi Rahul - I added a new hint yesterday that gives the next number in the sequence. You might want to check it as it doesn't match yours.