# Ad-hoc number sequence to solve 3

Tags: number-sequence

Learning from each [prior question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75410/an-ad-hoc-number-sequence-to-solve-2/75411) I've designed. Working toward a standard-style question, though not quite there yet. In the interim, here's a tester..

12, 15, 19, 29, 44, 51, ... ?

Your options are:

- 61
- 65
- 66
- 70
- 72

Hint:

> Just as haiku follows a set format, I'm working to a set format here. To get from one term to the next, I employ three set mathematical calculations - although in this quiz, the boundary for 'calculation' is not clear. Is it 3? Or is it 4? We'll decide once the solution comes out.

Answer (score 1):

I gonna try my attempt:

> 12
>  (+3)=
>  15
>  (+4)=
>  19
>  (+3+4+3)10=
>  29
>  (+(3*4)+3)15=
>  44
>  (+3+4)7=
>  51
>  (+(3*4)+3)15=
>  **66**

Comment: Ok, nice try, but not the pattern I used. I'll add a hint to the question.

Comment: @youcantryreachingme updated answer

Comment: Hi Mukyuu - no, that's not it.